# How should we promote our site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Let's face it: our site has pretty low activity at the moment. We have fewer than 200 visits per day, and our questions per day has dropped to less than 1. However, we've answered well over 90% of our questions, and we have almost two answers per question (note that there's often only one correct answer!). In short, the problem is that we don't have enough users.

There are many websites, blogs, forums and clubs about retrocomputing. A great deal of these people won't have even heard of this site. We need to get more people involved. But how?

If you have any ideas, post them in answers below. If you need help or to expand on them, post a question using the tag [site-promotion](/questions/tagged/site-promotion), and link to it in an answer to this question (optional).

With all your ideas, together we can help this site to grow!

Answer (score 6):

**Community Promotion Adverts**

Graduated sites show little promotion advertisements in the right-hand panel of their front page.  Every year a question is put onto the site's meta asking which other sites should be promoted and how.  The highest voted adverts on that question get shown.

Example requests for 2016 are: [SuperUser](https://meta.superuser.com/q/11127/247927) and [Android Users](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2067/39930) to name but two.

I've seen questions get closed on StackOverflow that would have been good on Retrocomputing. If we promote ourselves on sites such as these, we could get more traffic.

It is a bit late in the day for 2016 but not too late - and we can always prepare for 2017.

We need to put together a little promo or two (300 x 250 pixels) and post them as answers on a target site's meta question.  Perhaps another question here can ask for which sites we should target and what our advert should look like.

For example, I knocked this up in two minutes.  I'm sure we can do better.
[image: Witt's End from "Adventure"]

Comment: [Arqade](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11204/community-promotion-ads-2016) is an obvious choice for a community ad.