# Call for Community Promotion Ads

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

As this [answer](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/326/276) to the question  [How should we promote our site?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/323/276)  seems to be well received (please keep adding answers to that question by the way). Here is a follow-up question:

What should our advertisements be and on what sites should we put them?

We can tailor our ads to the target site.  For example, an ad on Arqade could look different to one on Ask Different.  Of course there is no requirement to tailor if we feel it is unnecessary.

So, please get the creative juices flowing and post here some suggested adverts and the site(s) targeted.  Note: graduated sites only, not other beta sites.

The rules are:

- The image must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there
  must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

The ads will then be posted as answers to the appropriate questions on the target site's metas.  They will then need to receive upvotes there in order to be displayed.

Comment: As the lists of community promotion ads are refreshed annually.  With a new year starting, the call can be renewed...

Comment: That sounds like a good plan. See [TL](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42627057#42627057).

Answer (score 8):

### Arqade

Well, it took five days but I think it was worth it. This 16.8KB PNG image is 600x500 pixels, so it will display crisp, high-quality pixel art even on Retina displays.

<s>I haven't written an alt-text yet, so if anyone has any suggestions as to what it should be please leave a comment.</s> I've written an alt text, but it's not very good. Suggestions for improvements would still be great!

---

[image: An advert for Retrocomputing Stack Exchange, featuring Pac-man, Space Invaders and Tetris. Remember these? Come to Retrocomputing Stack Exchange and share your knowledge!]

Comment: Posted on GameDev Meta [here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2262/76961).

Comment: That's GameDev meta.  Did you also want to post on Gaming Meta?

Comment: Posted on Arqade Meta [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12066/145997).

Comment: At the actual display size, the text on this is too small to read.

Comment: @angussidney If you have (an Apple ][ emulator (AppleWin's great for this) ([screen editing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/569/278) makes it easier) and) enough time, could you mock up a text layout that would fit a smaller space (i.e. bigger text)?

Comment: Reposted on [GameDev](//gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2321/76961) and [Arqade](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12066/145997), because the ads got some support last year.

Comment: The arqade (gaming.se) one now has 6 upvotes (enough to be displayed), but the game _dev_ one only has 2. :(

Comment: They both received 6 upvotes last year, so [GameDev](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2631/76961) and [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12877/145997) and seriously this can't be our only ad for _three years_.